App very buggy when updating published properties
My apps data workflow is causing the UI to be very buggy when fetching more data which causes me to wonder the best practice for storing/displaying/fetching data, the setup I have works as follow:
The very top view in the hierarchy stores classes @StateObject var messageViewModel = MessageViewModel() that contain @Published arrays of data. Then the class is injected into the main ContentView via envirnmentObject .environmentObject(messageViewModel). To access the classes data in a subview I use @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: messageViewModel. I use this EnvironmentObject viewModel in the subview to store the users data in @Published variables. When the user navigates to someone's profile, my backend fetches the data and inserts it into the @Published array. My subviews directly access the @Published data like so viewModel.users and present it inside a scrollview for example using a ForEach.
I don't believe this approach is optimal since my UI gets buggy when data is inserted into these @Published properties. It cases my animations to stop working for a second. I'm wondering how I could refactor my setup so that data is handled in a proper manner so that my animations work when transitioning to a new view that caches data.
import SwiftUI
import Combine

// ViewModel with @Published array of data
class MessageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = []

    // Simulate fetching data from backend
    func fetchMoreUsers() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            let newUsers = [
                User(id: UUID(), name: "John Doe"),
                User(id: UUID(), name: "Jane Smith")
            ]
            self.users.append(contentsOf: newUsers)
        }
    }
}

struct User: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var messageViewModel = MessageViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(messageViewModel)
                //My app has about 20 .environmentObject()'s
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MessageViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: UserProfileView()) {
                    Text("Go to Profile")
                }
                .padding()
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.fetchMoreUsers()
                }) {
                    Text("Fetch More Users")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UserProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MessageViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
                Text(user.name)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Simulate initial data fetch
            if viewModel.users.isEmpty {
                viewModel.fetchMoreUsers()
            }
        }
    }
}


Note, NavigationView is deprecated you should use NavigationStack.
I don't see any animation in your code, and this is where you say the problem is.

@workingdogsupportUkraine the code is just to give an idea of my apps structure. I really wanted an overview of the best practice to utilize. Thanks for the deprecation tip.

You do not need to say Swift in the title; you've said that in the tags.

Apple is replacing ObservableObject with Observable because it is so inefficient. having 20 of them in an app is unsustainable. You have to re-architect your app to use architectures that are more appropriate. Also, I think you are missing the essence of MVVM, View <> ViewModel (one to one) is how it is supposed to work not Views <> ViewModels (many to many). 20 view models at the app level isn't architecture at all.

@loremipsum each of my viewModels at the app level is specific to a different part of my app. So I have multiple because I needed one for messages, users, etc. I also declared them all at the app level so the data persists even after the tab/view is switched. When I had the viewModels declared as normal state objects in the low level tabs/views switching to another view caused the viewmodel to be destroyed since the view is no longer in the hierarchy, I need it to persist so I dont have to query my backend again. How would you recommend I restructure?

Those aren’t view models it’s called spaghetti when everything knows about everything and there is no modularization. Look into TCA, Viper, dependency injection. Apple has plenty of samples on maintaining server copies locating and reconvering view state.
